# Why does this code only output the else statement?

Tags: python, keyword

So I'm trying to write a program that will ask for your problem, search for a keyword in that query and then output a solution if certain keywords are found.

This is my code so far:

```
def keyword_searcher():
    user_query = input("Enter your problem:\n")
    with open("user_query.txt", "a+") as query:
        query.write(user_query.lower())
        for line in query:
            for word in line.split():
                if word == "backlight" or "display" or "cracked" or "touchscreen":
                    f = open("Solutions1.txt", "r")
                    solution_one  = f.read()
                    print ("Keyword for screen problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_one)
                    f.close()
                elif word == "battery" or "charger" or "usb" or "charge":
                    f_two = open("Solutions2.txt", "r")
                    solution_two = f_two.read()
                    print ("Keyword for battery problem found:\n")
                    print(solution_two)
                    f.close()
                elif word == "virus" or "hacked" or "infected" or "antivirus":
                    f_three = open("Solutions3.txt", "r")
                    solution_three = f_three.read()
                    print ("Keyword for virus problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_three)
                else:
                    print ("Please be more specific\n")
                    keyword_searcher()
```

But when I run it, I input my problem but then *nothing gets outputted*.

**EDIT**: As suggested, my new code is this. It takes into account the file position (with `seek(0)`) and checks correctly if a `word` is in a list of keywords:

```
def keyword_searcher():
    user_query = input("Enter your problem:\n")
    with open("user_query.txt", "a+") as query:
        query.write(user_query.lower())
        query.seek(0)
        for line in query:
            for word in line.split():
                if word in ("backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen"):
                    f = open("Solutions1.txt", "r")
                    solution_one  = f.read()
                    print ("Keyword for screen problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_one)
                    f.close()
                elif word in ("battery", "charger", "usb", "charge"):
                    f_two = open("Solutions2.txt", "r")
                    solution_two = f_two.read()
                    print ("Keyword for battery problem found:\n")
                    print(solution_two)
                    f.close()
                elif word in ("virus", "hacked", "infected", "antivirus"):
                    f_three = open("Solutions3.txt", "r")
                    solution_three = f_three.read()
                    print ("Keyword for virus problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_three)
                else:
                    print ("Please be more specific\n")
                    keyword_searcher()
```

Problem is, it now runs the `else` statement, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** your `else` clause is problematic, it shouldn't call `keyword_searcher` again. When you enter a sentence like:

```
Enter your problem:
My Problem is duh duh virus
```

It will call the function again and won't check the rest of the line. Instead, you should simply continue on to the next word in the `line`:

```
# how your else clause should look:
else:
    print ("Please be more specific\n")
```

Now everyword will be evaluated and the other clauses will evaluate to `True` if a correct keyword is present.

---

Your opening with `a+` this places the "file pointer" to the end of the file so no lines can be read. You should instead open with `r` if you want to iterate through the lines.

The the following file for example and notice the differences in `file.tell()`:

```
>>> with open("jupyter_notebook_config.py", "a+") as f:
...    print(f.tell())
>>> 22821

>>> with open("jupyter_notebook_config.py", "r") as f:
...    print(f.tell())
>>> 0
```

In the first case we're at the end of the file so `for line in f` just doesn't have anything. In the second case we have all lines available so iterating through it yields the lines in the file.

What you could do is use `f.seek(0)` to go to the beginning and then start iterating.

Comment: I opened it with a+ because i thought it would allow me to read and write - guess i was wrong. But what would i use to read and write in a text file because opening with r is read only mode.

Comment: I have now changed it to seek to 0 and fixed the incorrect use of OR but now whenever i input  a keyword (e.g. "cracked") it just outputs the else statement...

Comment: Can someone help these are only partial solutions to a bigger problem

Comment: What exactly are you entering when it prompts you for some text @DidgeriDuck?

Comment: @Jim I'm just inputting a sentence with one of the keywords in it e.g. "My phone has a virus" ... virus being the keyword

Comment: Also, this now spams the else statement and then at the end of the output it recognises the keyword... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `print` in the `else`, remove it. It searches for **each word in the line sequentially**. If the matching keyword is at the end it is going to get matched in the end.

Comment: What would i put in the else statement, because at the moment the code just outputs nothing even if there is a keyword in the query :|

Comment: I wouldn't put anything in it. Additionally we've maxed out the comments here, I really can't check whether it outputs something or not since I don't have the files you're using nor the time to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is that you are using the logical [OR](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) incorrectly, you should use:

```
if word == "backlight" or word == "display" or word == "cracked" or word == "touchscreen"
```

You can fix it nicely in Python by using `in`:

```
if word in ("backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen")
```

After you fix this, you would want to notice that opening your file with `a+` is incorrect in your case, for the reason stated in Jim's answer. Change it to `r`:

```
with open("user_query.txt", "r") as query
```